# Align Image and comment like on youtube comment section for responsive site

Tags: css, html

How to align image and two span's in one row

```
        <img src="../images/profile/profile.png" class="img" />
        <span class="name">Firt Name</span>
        <span class="comment">
            This is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently this is end of count.
        </span>
```

Fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/m3qyhoab/

I change image and span display properties to block etc.. but still didn't work

Comment: how would you like to align? all 3 elements in the same row, aligned to left, right, centered....?

Comment: like this? http://fiddle.jshell.net/m3qyhoab/12/

Comment: add `display:inline-block` to the wrapper and `display:block;` to all floated elements within the wrapper.also you are making the two span elements have a width of 100% this does not allow them to float side-by-side try removing the width

Comment: I would like Image to take all vertical space and and keep name and comment aligned to left, Table is one way of doing it but should we use tables, I tried to change span display properties to table-cell but that dit not work.

Comment: @Anonymous.X, doesnt work http://fiddle.jshell.net/m3qyhoab/19/

Comment: @nevermind, in your case name & comment are in same line.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker, i guess you can change HTML (add wrappers if needed), because, basically - you need two wrappers/blocks, floated....

Answer (score 0):

Try using a table:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="http://i450.photobucket.com/albums/qq229/veraqueen/80X80-1.jpg" class="img" /></td>
            <td><span class="name">Firt Name</span></td>
            <td> <span class="comment">
                This is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently this is end of count.
            </span></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if is the behaviour you're expecting but...Try this:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/m3qyhoab/23/

[image]

Comment: Something similar to you tube comments section

Answer (score 0):

***CSS***

```
.wrapper {
    max-width:800px;
    margin:30px auto;
    background-color:#ccc;
    display:inline-block;
}
.img {
    width:80px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:15px
}
.name {
    float:left;
    width:80px;
}
.comment {
    float:left;
    width:600px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/m3qyhoab/25/)

> For Yours to work properly You need to HardCode your Width to every Class using Float

Comment: It is responsive behavior which is making it difficult, otherwise it is fine, If nothing works then tables i the only choice as YouTube is also using tables

Answer (score 0):

If you want your image to take vertical space and keep name and comment aligned to its right. You may consider doing [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/m3qyhoab/27/).

Avoid using `<table>`. For a more structured solution, you may use bootstrap aswell

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[Fidler](http://fiddle.jshell.net/m3qyhoab/41/)

```
.wrapper {
    max-width:800px;
    margin:30px auto;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.img {
    width:80px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:15px
}
.name {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
}
.comment {
    float:left;
    width:605px;
}
```

What I mentioned :

- You forget to close css with ;
- You mix relative size in % with absolute in pixels.
- Implement my code and it will work fine.

p.s. Dont forget to move Result window to left if it does not show in one line.